# Associate CSS Style to ASP.Net control

Tags: asp.net, css

So i know in that i can design a style for a HTML control by either using CSS-class or CSS-id association.

For instance, HTML:

CSS:

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
}

    div#divHeader
    {
        left: 1px;
        right: 1px;
        top: 5px;
        min-width: 90%;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML:

```
        <div id="divHeader">
...
        </div>
```

#### Question:

Can i use this same Association for ASP.Net controls or will i have to implicitely declare the association with the CSSClass attribute?

CSS:

```
#lblTitle
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  ...
  <td id="tdTitle">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Style="font-size: 46pt; vertical-align: middle;" runat="server" />
  </td>
  ...
```

I would assume it would work but need some verification.  If i have to use the CSSclass attribute i will but would rather reserve that attribute for other generic style development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can i use this same Association for ASP.Net controls or will i have to implicitely declare the association with the CSSClass attribute?

Answer is yes.
But as you might be kowing `div#divHeader` is a id css. It will be applied to the every `div` having the id `divHeader`.
But you should aslo be knowing the difference between a `html-control` and `asp.net control`. 
The `id` attribute changes at runtime in asp.net that can be due to many reasone.

1. Your are using `master` and `content pages`.
2. Your are using `user controls`.
3. If you are using `gridview` or similar controls.

In the condition `1` and `2` you can use `static id` if you are using asp.net 4.o and above as follows.

```
 ClientIDMode =static
```

But in case of gridview you can use parent child or herical approach. You will have to understand the rendering of html on the browser.
Only then you will able to create a good css classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Define the CSS with class or matching ID
2. Determine what type of HTML element is rendered (span, input, div, etc) and build your styles around that.

Option 1 wouldn't be an issue really when using classes, aside from having to put class="yourclass" on your controls tag.  I tend to stray away from ID tags unless there is a defined reason for styling just this one element.

Option 2:   You would have to go in and figure out how to hierarchically define your css based on the rendered HTML from your form;  figuring out that "" when rendered, etc.